# Having multiple HTTP-Server running next to nginx on the same machine

Tags: nginx, httpserver

I have multiple HTTP servers running on the same machine. Only the nginx is listening to the HTTP port and forwards the requests to the other programs.

Now I'm adding a service that needs to receive post requests directly (without them being buffered). I already read that this isn't possible, though the posts are about a year old so I'm hoping there's a way to accomplish this in nginx 1.5.

Is there another way to have multiple HTTP server running on the same machine?

Edit: Every server has to answer requests from the http port. Which server handles the request is determined by the Hostname in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

When your server has multiple IP's, You can bind services to explictly selected IP instead of default '*' or 0.0.0.0

When your clients can be segregated by their IP's, You can bind services to different ports and route packets using iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -s 10.20.30.0/24 -j REDIRECT --to-port 81
```

Iptables can check not only headers, but also content via "-m string" extension.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sadly my server has only one address and I can't distinguish by client either.

Comment: Okay, what should be server selection rule for your case? Try to say in free form. Hostname?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't very clear in my question.
Yes, the Hostname determines which process the request should be sent to.

Comment: iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "Host: yourdomain.com" --algo bm -j REDIRECT --to-port 81

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion. I never used iptables before and what I found online so far suggests that it can't operate on http-level to find out the hostname. Running it leaves a message in dmesg:  
    x_tables: ip_tables: REDIRECT target: only valid in nat table, not filter

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple processes on the same machine, call them HTTP servers, or anything else, the only "limit" is that they cannot listen in on the same port, they will each need to listen on a different port to work.

Otherwise they will complain that the port is already in use and "die".